# No subheader on the frontend with css_styled_content on TYPO3 v8

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

When css_styled_content is used, the subheader is not seen at all on the frontend.
However replacing css_style_content with fluid_styled_content, the subheader is shown.. but some other things get bad, like images out of dimensiosn.. So I would like to make it work with css_styled_content, even though it is deprecated, and will be removed in the future.

I am using templavoila for templating. Thought that perhaps some typoscript was written in the localprocessing xml for subheader rendering, searched the database and found nothing related.

The subheader is in text CType.

Perhaps this typoscript is deprecated/needed to be changed?

```
    tt_content.text.5 < tt_content.header.20
    tt_content.text.5 {
      dataWrap = <h4 class="subheader subheader-{field:layout}">|</h4>
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the subheader is already part of CSS-styled-content's

```
lib.stdheader
```

which again is already assigend to the CType rendering of

```
tt_content.text
```

there is no need to add it manually to tt_content.text.5

The breaking change you might be looking for can be found in lib.sdtheader itself, since the subheader is rendered within HTML5 doctypes only.

```
if {
    isTrue {
        field = subheader
    }
    value = html5
    equals.data = TSFE:config|config|doctype
}
```

So setting the correct doctype should do the job in this case.

Comment: So can you post the snippet you used to configure the doctype?
And could you put something like:

123 = TEXT
123.data = TSFE:config|config|doctype

somewhere into your template, so you can see the actual value of that key?

Comment: In one config files was some weird overriding of stdHeader.20  
      lib.stdheader.20 < lib.stdheader.5
      lib.stdheader.5 >   An interesting way to clear the stdHeader, not sure why it was being cleared, if I find out I will complete the answer. 

Your answer is very to the theme and people might stumble upon this. I will therefore mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: By the way, perhaps you know why the logic for subheader is so weird? I don't see any causality between subheader and html5 - it's not like some html5 only tag is being used, but regular h tags.

Comment: I consider this a bug, since in Fluid Styled Content there is no doctype condition at all.